# How could I split an array into subarrays with different dimension with numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, split, concatenation

i have to divide an array in 3 different subarrays of dimension `w=(N,2), b=(N,1), v=(1,N)`. They've been concatenated before, with

```
u= np.concatenate((b,w.flatten(),v),axis=None)
```

but now I need to divide and get the original ones `(w,b,v)`.

I'm trying with `np.array_split` but don't know how to do this.

Comment: If the arrays have the shape you say then that concatenation would not be possible (different numbers of dimensions and incompatible shapes).

Comment: Could you provide some input data and expected output?

Comment: Please show a working example of the concatenation, along with the input arrays (random or arange is fine). Even if your split does not work, please show what you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can individually obtain these back, with:

```
b = u[:n].reshape(-1, 1)
v = u[-n:].reshape(1, -1)
w = u[n:-n].reshape(-1, 2)
```

This works since `u` is a vector with *4×N* elements, that looks like:

```
u = [ b00, b10, …, bn0,
      w00, w01, w10, w11, …, wn0, wn1,
      v00, v01, …, v0n]
```

So it is matter of taking the first *n* elements, the last *n* elements, and the elements in between.

For example for `n=5`, we can randomly generate three arrays:

```
>>> w
array([[ 1., -0.],
       [-1.,  2.],
       [ 0., -2.],
       [-1.,  1.],
       [-1., -1.]])
>>> b
array([[ 0.],
       [-1.],
       [-0.],
       [-1.],
       [-0.]])
>>> v
array([[-0., -0., -0., -0., -2.]])
```

then `u` is:

```
>>> u
array([ 0., -1., -0., -1., -0.,  1., -0., -1.,  2.,  0., -2., -1.,  1.,
       -1., -1., -0., -0., -0., -0., -2.])
```

we can retrieve the data back with:

```
>>> u[:n].reshape(-1, 1)  # b
array([[ 0.],
       [-1.],
       [-0.],
       [-1.],
       [-0.]])
>>> u[-n:].reshape(1, -1)  # v
array([[-0., -0., -0., -0., -2.]])
>>> u[n:-n].reshape(-1, 2)  # w
array([[ 1., -0.],
       [-1.,  2.],
       [ 0., -2.],
       [-1.,  1.],
       [-1., -1.]])
```